# Cerrar div con "x"

Tags: javascript, html, css

me gustaría saber como hacer para que la gente pueda cerrar un div que tiene un anuncio adsense dando click a una "x"

Aca dejo una imagen de lo que busco:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes añadir este código, es simple para que puedas adaptarlo, no utiliza jquery sólo Javascript puro css y html

```js
var cerraranuncio = anuncio => {
  document.getElementById(anuncio).style.display = "none";
}
```

```css
.anuncio {
  width: 400px;
  height: 100px;
  background: lightblue;
  display:block
}

.boton {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<div id="primeranuncio" class="anuncio">
  Anuncio
  <span class="boton" onclick="cerraranuncio('primeranuncio')">x</span>
</div>
```

Edito: Puedes añadir un temporizador para que cada cierto tiempo vuelva a aparecer el anuncio, te puede ser útil

```js
var cerraranuncio = anuncio => {
  document.getElementById(anuncio).style.display = "none";

  setTimeout(() => {
    document.getElementById(anuncio).style.display = "block";
  }, 4000) //cuatro segundos

}
```

```css
.anuncio {
  width: 400px;
  height: 100px;
  background: lightblue;
  display: block;
}

.boton {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<div id="primeranuncio" class="anuncio">
  Anuncio
  <span class="boton" onclick="cerraranuncio('primeranuncio')">x</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Gracias, es perfecto, pero sabes como puedo moverlo? es decir, para ponerlo arriba de los controles por ejemplo, con "top"?

Comment: Lo estás usando para un reproductor de video? podrías usar `position:absolute; margin:0 auto; botton:30px;`esos ultimos 30 pixeles son tal vez los controles, no estoy seguro si funcionará en un reproductor, pero en un div sí lo hará

Answer (score 1):

Creo que esto es lo que estás buscando:

Es un ejemplo con una ventana modal:

```
<button class="abrir">Abrir modal</button>

<!-- HTML -->
<div id="ejemplo" class="modal">
  <!-- Modal content -->
  <div class="modal-content">
  <span class="cerrar">&times;</span>
  <h1>Hola, esto es un Modal</h1>
  </div> <!-- fin modal content -->
</div> <!-- fin modal -->
```

El CSS Para el ejemplo:

```
<style type="text/css">
    .modal {
        display: none;
        position: fixed;
        z-index: 1;
        border-radius: 10px;
        left: 0;
        top: 0;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        overflow: auto;
        background-color: rgb(0,0,0);
        background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.8); 
    }

    .modal-content {
      border-radius: 10px;
        background-color: #fefefe;
        margin: 15% auto;
        padding: 20px;
        border: 1px solid #888;
        width: 80%; 
    }

    .cerrar {
        color: #aaa;
        float: right;
        font-size: 28px;
        font-weight: bold;
    }

    .cerrar:hover,
    .cerrar:focus {
        color: black;
        text-decoration: none;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
</style>
```

Ahora, con este pequeño evento de jQuery, podrás abrir y cerrar el Modal, en cuanto a tu `X`, en el `<span>` tienes para cerrarlo como tu quieres.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

  $(document).on('click', '.abrir', function () {
    $('#ejemplo').show();
  });

  $(document).on('click', '.cerrar', function () {
    $('#ejemplo').hide();
  });
});
</script>
```

Sin olvidarnos de haber añadido jQuery:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Creo que a partir de este código, se podría solventar tu duda!
Saludos

Comment: Hay un error en algun lado, no me apare el `h1` del ejemplo

Comment: Pero, si que se abre la ventana Modal ?

Comment: No se abra nada, lo probe en un html vacio y no carga nada

Comment: Se me olvidó agregar el botón de abrir modal, con el class .abrir, revisa mi respuesta, y encontrarás un button para añadir al body.

Comment: Te sirvió mi respuesta? :)

Comment: No, no hace nada el boton, y yo quiero que esté por defecto abierto, y que aparezca una x para cerrar, como se puede ver en la foto, si es que la viste.